Unity HTTP Request not working on Device (Android)
Hi i have an graphql endpoint with no ssl it is http.
I set Allow Downloads over HTTP* = always allowed from my player settings before the build.
And this is my android manifest.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <!-- This allows HTTP connections -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-96----------"/>

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>


My requests works fine on the unity but i published my app to store and it is not working also i cannot see the erros .

What status is being returned from the Request?  Is it 200 OK or a 400/500 Error.  If you are getting a response than issue is not SSL/TLS.  A SSL/TLS error will not give a response.  You may have issue with credentials when you do not use HTTPS.  Did you check the log files on Android? https://support.google.com/android/answer/12986432?hl=en

If you don't find a different way you can simply look at the traffic. As it is plaintext HTTP traffic you can capture it using an app that captures all the traffic as pcap file (e.g. via PCAPDroid) and then look at it in Wireshark. Then you will see if the request is performed and what the HTTP response is.
